# OpenGL Vs DirectX Today?

Tags: opengl, directx, gpu

So there was a popular article a few years back titled [OpenGL 3 & DirectX 11: The War Is Over](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/opengl-directx,2019.html) then there was this article titled [OpenGL vs DirectX: The War Is Far From Over](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2011/10/opengl-vs-directx-the-war-is-far-from-over/)

I would like to know what is the stand today ? What is the future of OpenGL when compared to DirectX ? Is OpenGL catching up with latest specifications?

There is this recent article [Return of the DirectX vs. OpenGL Debates](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7890/return-of-the-directx-vs-opengl-debates) but it doesn't say anything clearly about questions i asked.

Comment: Why is the opengl-es tag on this question? I don't think DirectX is even available on the platforms where one would typically use OpenGL-ES (eg: Android and iOS).

Comment: there is something called Direct 3d Mobile(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D_Mobile#Direct3D_Mobile) available for windows phone platform

Comment: Why negative Votes ? What is wrong with questio n?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the future of OpenGL when compared to DirectX

By the numbers OpenGL, especially its embedded variant clearly dominates the market. Practically every smartphone (except for Windows Phone) sold these days relies on OpenGL for its graphics output.

Also with Valve's strong push for the Linux market and their Steam Boxes, OpenGL gets another push. Other game makers and vendors are following into their steps, with many Triple-A game engines getting Linux ports these days.

> Is OpenGL catching up with latest specifications?

These days OpenGL tends to be ahead of hardware development. The latest OpenGL specification is OpenGL-4.4, but the majority of GPUs and drivers found out there are still at OpenGL-4.3 (note that the major version number of OpenGL relates to the hardware class).

Comment: AMD ***just*** (like a week ago) released drivers that fully implement 4.4 (on Radeon HD 5000+ (circa Q4 2009) GPUs), by the way. Now we just have to wait a few years for Intel to catch up ;)